# couchdb map-reduce and grouping

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I am attempting to get a count of unique events for an object (lets say a video):

Here are my documents:

```
{
  "type":"View",
  "video_id": "12300",
  "user_id": 3
}

{
  "type":"View",
  "video_id": "12300",
  "user_id": 1
}
{
  "type":"View",
  "video_id": "45600",
  "user_id": 3
}
```

I'm trying to get a unique (by `user_id`) count of views for each video

I assume I want to map my data like so:

```
function(doc) {
        if (doc.type === 'View') {
           emit([doc.video_id, doc.user_id], 1);
        }
    },
```

But I don't understand how to reduce it down to unique users per video, or am I going about this wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look at the [`group_level`](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) view parameter. It will allow you to change what field(s) the grouping occurs on.

By using `group_level = 1`, in this case it will group by `video_id`. Using `group_level = 2`, it will group on both `video_id` **and** `user_id`.

Answer (score 4):

Add ?group=true after the request URL. That groups identical keys together as input for the reduce function:

```
function(keys, values, rereduce){
  return sum(values);
}
```

That should do it.

Note that keys and values are unzipped lists of keys and their values. With grouping on the keys are all identical for each call of the reduce.